# customizing regex to append the url correctly

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get the image url from page source. Here is my regex

```
<?php       

$url='http://www.biznessapps.com';    
$data = file_get_contents($url);        
$logo = get_logo($data);    
echo $logo;    
function get_logo($html)     
{    
    //preg_match_all('', $html, $matches);
    //preg_match_all('~\b((\w+ps?://)?\S+(png|jpg))\b~im', $html, $matches);
    if(preg_match_all('/\bhttps?:\/\/\S+(?:png|jpg)\b/', $html, $matches))
    {  
        echo "First";                   
        return $matches[0][0];
    }
    else
    { 
        if(preg_match_all('~\b((\w+ps?://)?\S+(png|jpg))\b~im', $html, $matches))
        {  
            echo "Second";
            return $matches[0][0];
        }
        else
            return null;
    }    
}    
?>
```

For some url like: `http://www.biznessapps.com` regex give result `/frontend/images/logo.png`. Which is the subfolder path to image url.

What validation should I use so that if there is subfolder path to image, it should converted to absolute image url that is `http://www.biznessapps.com/frontend/images/logo.png` for above case.

For some cases user enters url like `http://www.biznessapps.com/` so if I directly append `/frontend/images/logo.png` with main url then it converted to `http://www.biznessapps.com//frontend/images/logo.png` which is again wrong.

Can anyone suggest change in regex to get rid of this?

Comment: First at all, how can you assume that the first image url you find is the image you are looking for?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: I am not looking for any particular image. Any image on that page is sufficient for me

Answer (score 1):

> *What validation should I use so that if there is subfolder path to image, it should converted to absolute image url*

You want to use [UrlToAbsolute](http://publicmind.in/blog/urltoabsolute/) php library that converts relative urls to absolute.

Here is a sample code:

```
require('url_to_absolute.php');
echo url_to_absolute('http://www.biznessapps.com/', '/frontend/images/logo.png');
```

> **url_to_absolute:** returns false on failure, otherwise returns the absolute url. If the *$relativeUrl* is a valid absolute url, it is returned without any modification.